# Refreshing the newly added dom if has data jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, binding

I have created the select input some option and on that option change it will go to the server and fetch some data and if has data it will append the select load data in option tag similary for the added data to if has data on server it will go and show on and on but i need to refresh and dom on the same event

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var data;
   var child1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
   var child2 = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pinapple'];
   var child3 = ['php', 'jsp', 'python', 'asp'];
   $('#mainInit').on('change', function() {
     //ajax request runs and from the value of mainInit and loads some data to append in option
     $('.wrapper').append('<select class="child" > select something</select>');
     if ($(this).val() == "1") {
       data = child1;
     } else if ($(this).val() == "2") {
       data = child2;
     } else {
       data = child3;
     }

     $.each(data, function(index, value) {
       $('.child').append('<option>' + value + '</option>');
     });


   })

 })
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <select name="" id="mainInit">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

and similary there will be function for the

```
$('body').on('change','.child',function(){
// here it will do the same work as the main init check if the option has value and load
})
```

and every time i click 1 the next thing append and if 2 the next thing append the thing should be. When i click 1 if should append and when i click it should remove all the child child child infinity dom added and same for the rest
    https://jsfiddle.net/3cnd2fgL/  is what i tried

http://www.kaymu.com.np/createproduct/start/ this what i want to accomplish the category section

Comment: Have you tried this $select.selectmenu("refresh", true);

Comment: I am not using selectmenu ui

Comment: What do you mean by _refreshing_? I am not able to understand your problem